# Only one connection to database and use functions, C++

Tags: c++, mysql, database, connection, pool

I have a class to connect MySQL database. This class has 4 methods. (insert, getResults etc.) I don't want to create database connection in every method. So i want an init() when we create this object. Is connection pool solution of my problem? How can i solve?

Have 4 methods like that:

```
bool DataAccessObject::getResults(short int data, std::vector<FaceRecord>* rec)
{
//    DataAccessObject *temp = new DataAccessObject();

    bool ret = false;

    try{
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;
        sql::PreparedStatement *prepStmt;

        /* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");

        /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
        con->setSchema("test");

        std::stringstream s;
        s << "SELECT * FROM Amts WHERE "<< data <<" = "<< data <<"";

        prepStmt = con->prepareStatement (s.str());
        res = prepStmt->executeQuery();

        while(res->next()){
            tempFR.uuId = res->getInt64("uuId");
            tempFR.cameraNo = res->getInt("cameraNo");
            tempFR.age = res->getInt("age");
            tempFR.gender = res->getInt("gender");
            tempFR.time = res->getString("time");
            tempFR.image = res->getString("image");
            rec->push_back(tempFR);
        }


        //return true;
        ret = true;
    }

    catch (sql::SQLException &e)
    {

        std::cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        std::cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        std::cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        std::cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << std::endl;

    }

    return ret;

}
```

Comment: You just solved the problem yourself. It's unclear what you're asking, since you didn't even type all the methods, and noone can possibly know what class are you really using.

Comment: Check the documentation for the database driver. It may natively implement connection pooling, in which case there's no need for you to do so.

Comment: i have added a method to my question. I want to remove "Create a connection" field and before.

Comment: You do not want to pass the connection?

Comment: I want to pass the connection. So I want to create connection in constructor of this class, or in an init function, then use this methods(insert,retrieve) without create connection.

Comment: I meant that the connection could be passed into the function as an argument or you could use the suggestion by Dannie Sim.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern) so that your init is called only once when you create it.